# Leave a cell blank until data is entered in different cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help me to type this formula: `=IF($F5>0,I4/$F5,0)` 

inside this formula: `=IF(F5="","",[I-want-to-type-it-here])`

The first formula `=IF($F5>0,I4/$F5,0)` is to calculate the profit margin, and the second is to leave the cell empty until I enter data in a different cell.

[image: Example for the error I got in google sheets]

Comment: =IF(D5="","",D5*(1+35%)+0.50)

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for your answer!
I already tried it by using conditional formatting but didn't work, I've already had a formula on the F cell, how can I add this formula too?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It is obvious answer. Seek your guidance being a Senior Person whether such situations be tackled through comments or Answer be provided. Not answering does not close question.

Comment: I do not understand..............just replace the old formula with he new formula..........

Comment: @skkakkar If it is a simple formula, I will use a Comment.  If the formula requires an explanation, I will answer.

Comment: It works! thank you Gary's Student for your help (y) I appreciate it

Comment: @skkakkar I am confused by your comment... Are you suggesting Gary should seek guidance from himself or a senior person? Gary has done **so** much on here that your efforts would be better directed at providing an answer instead of being "picky"...

Comment: Gary's Student: please can you help me to enter this formula =IF($F3>0,I3/$F3,0) in the formula you answered to me with? because it has IF also and I didn't know how to type it with the right method! Thank you

Comment: @Solar Mike I have high regards for Gary. I sought his personal advice as I face similar situations where comment could be enough as Gary clarified.I had a doubt about question closure as perhaps such questions are closed by community edit. It was a genuine doubt and seeking guidance from a senior member may not be wrong.  I have yet to learn a lot from persons like you ,Tim , Jeeped, Sidharth, , Garry, scot craner to name a few. It hardly meant any offence. If it has hurt someone feelings,, I publicly apologize for it. Regards.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent please if you can help me with the second problem I will be thankful to you

Comment: this formula =IF($F3>0,I3/$F3,0) calculate the profit margin, but after apply this formula =IF(D5="","",D5*(1+35%)+0.50) that you gave me, I get this error in the cell that calculate profit margin said: #DIV/0!

Comment: @Hamza edit your second problem into the original question clearly and explain why it does not work. Just from looking at it I would have expected it to work...

Comment: @SolarMike okay bro I'll do that thank you so much

Comment: The test of F3 being greater than 0 is the problem... check for empty with "" as Gary showed you before. if(f3="","",I3/$F3)

Comment: I don't know what you have in cell I3... if **you** are working in percentages then that's what you should get, but if you are working in barrels or boxes of dead fish... I focused on the error due to testing F3 to be greater than 0...

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for your answer bro, the formula you gave me works well :)

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF($F5>0, I4/$F5, 0), )
```

---

```
=IF(F5="", , 
 IF($F5>0, I4/$F5, 0))
```

---

```
=IF(F5="", , IFERROR(IF($F5>0, I4/$F5, 0), 
                     IF($F3>0, I3/$F3, 0)))
```