# Replace #DIV/0 error in cell to 0 or blank in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I tried with this formula `=IF(B2<>0,"0",B2/C2)` and I fixed the `#DIV/0` error. But the `B2/C2` won't work after I applied that formula on the cell!

Can someone help me to replace `#DIV/0` error in the cell to `0` or `blank` but at the same time when I put data in `B2` and `C2` cells I want to get the total after the completion of the division.

[screenshot to see an example for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbVgZ.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You had the solution given to you here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54847520/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to know if `C2` is 0 as this will produce an error. If `B2` is 0, you will just get 0

`0/C2` = `0`
`B2/0` = `Error`

---

Either of these will do to combat the above error produced when diving by 0

1. `=IF(C2 = 0, 0, B2/C2)`
2. `=IFERROR(B2/C2, 0)`

Comment: Notice you don't need to place quotes around `0` outputs from formulas. You only need quotes for string outputs.

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy the second one works with me `=IFERROR(B2/C2, 0)`

Comment: can you please help me with this: I want to make the cell blank if the B2 is blank or doesn't have any data on it, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBcxM.jpg

Comment: `IF(B2 = "", "", IFERROR(B2/C2, 0))`

Comment: I want to make the `D` cell have €0.00 if the `B` or `C` has a data, and make the `D` cell blank if `B` or `C` doesn't have a data.

Comment: `IF(COUNTA(B1:C1) = 2, IFERROR(B2/C2, 0), "")`

Comment: I tried with both but no one works with me, I get the formula like a text and this is a screenshot to see what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGJet.jpg